# How do I decode a double backslashed PERLQQ escaped string into Perl characters?

Tags: perl, utf8-decode

I read lines from a file which contains semi-utf8 encoding and I wish to convert it to Perl-internal representation for further operations.

file.in (plain ASCII):

```
MO\\xc5\\xbdN\\xc3\\x81
NOV\\xc3\\x81
```

These should translate to MOŽNÁ and NOVÁ.

I load the lines and upgrade them to proper utf8 notation, ie. `\\xc5\\xbd -> \x{00c5}\x{00bd}`. Then I would like to take this upgraded `$line` and make perl to represent it internally:

```
for my $line (@lines) {
    $line =~ s/x(..)/x{00$1}/g;
    eval { $l = "$line"; };
}
```

Unfortunately, without success.

Comment: Ah, you did not make it clear enough that your sample input file looks literally like that. I thought you had just tried to make make it clear what hex values are in there. Deleted my answer, because Daxim's is the correct one for such a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
use Encode qw(decode);
use Encode::Escape qw();

my $string =
    decode 'UTF-8',             # octets → characters
    decode 'unicode-escape',    # \x → octets
    decode 'ascii-escape',      # \\x → \x
    read_file 'file.in';
```

Read from the bottom upwards.